# Como recuperar o mês anterior ao atual com Java

Tags: java, data

Identifiquei a necessidade de conseguir o mês anterior ao atual. Por exemplo, hoje é 10/12/2021 e eu preciso retornar novembro.

Em uma primeira tentativa eu capturei o  `LocalDate.now().getMonth()` e diminui 1.
Só que o mês anterior a janeiro é dezembro, e no meu código fica 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende, você quer uma instância de `java.time.Month` ([que é o que `getMonth` retorna](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#getMonth--)), ou quer o valor numérico referente ao mês?

Enfim, se for a primeira opção, basta subtrair um mês do próprio `Month`:

```
Month anterior = LocalDate.now().getMonth().minus(1);
```

Mas se quer o valor numérico, pode ser:

```java
int anterior = LocalDate.now().getMonth().minus(1).getValue();

// OU
int anterior = LocalDate.now().minusMonths(1).getMonthValue();
```

Os métodos `minus` e `minusMonths` já tratam dos casos em que o mês atual é janeiro, retornando corretamente dezembro do ano anterior.

Comment: é isso mesmo o que eu preciso.